# MapView build: Expose secret google maps api key in app.json, is it safe?

Tags: expo, eas, mapview

I am building a new react native  app with expo which uses google maps (MapView library),
But, deploying a map with Google Maps requires to explecitly add maps api key in app.json as below :

```
“android”: {
“package”: “com.myapp.app”,
“googleServicesFile”: “./google-services.json”,
“adaptiveIcon”: {
“foregroundImage”: “./assets/adaptive-icon.png”,
“backgroundColor”: “#ffffff”
},
**“config”: {
** “googleMaps”: {**
** “apiKey”: **“…sensitive & secret value…”****
** }**
** }**
},**
```

In general, I store all my secret variables in Expo website as described in https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/#using-secrets-in-environment-variables
now i am feeling confused, on the hand, I can’t expose my secret variables in app.json, but, on the other hand it is madatory to expose it to support MapView Library.

is this safe? is there any  risk of stealing my api key ? Any recommendation and idea how to proceed?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of working on this issue, declaring secret key is inevitable,
Regardless of whether app uses React Native, Expo, or any other development framework, API keys required for direct connections between the app and an API are public and could be exposed;
SOLUTION: Restrict usage of the key
==> Learn how to restrict key for android and IOS, in this way, just your specefic app is allowed to consume the api key,

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

“android”: {
“package”: “com.myapp.app”,
“googleServicesFile”: “./google-services.json”,
“adaptiveIcon”: {
“foregroundImage”: “./assets/adaptive-icon.png”,
“backgroundColor”: “#ffffff”
},
config: {
    googleMaps: {
      apiKey: process.env.ANDROID_GOOGLE_MAPS_API,
    },
 }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

**imports:**

```
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker, Polyline } from "react-native-maps";
```

**component:**

```
  <MapView
     ref={mapRef}
     initialRegion={mapStartPositon}
     customMapStyle={customMapStyle}
     ...
     provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
   >
```

**app.json:**

```
...
,
"android": {
  "config": {
    "googleMaps": {
      "apiKey": "AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxm0" 
    }
  },
...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).